# Parent process not terminating

Tags: c, fork

I have a parent and child process both counting upto 50 and then terminate. The parent process waits till the child process has counted upto 50 and then exits. I have written the code but it is going in infinite loop :

```
int main()
{
   long int T_Child = 0, T_parent = 0;
   pid_t procid = fork();
   int T = 0;
   if(procid < 0)
   {
       printf("\nFailed");
       exit(0);
   }
   else if(procid == 0)
   {//child
        while(T_Child < 50)
        {
            printf("\nCHILD : %ld",T_Child);
            delay(2);
            T_Child++;
        }  
        exit(1);
   }
   else if(procid > 0)
   {//parent
       while(T_parent < 50)
       {
           printf("\nPARENT : %ld",T_parent);
           delay(2);
           T_parent++;
       }
       while(T_Child < 50)
       {//to ensure parent exits after child
           delay(1);
       }
       exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

I'm a novice in this field. Please help!

Comment: The variables *are not* shared between parent and child processes. The child is an isolated duplicate of the parent. Changes made in the child are not visible in the parent.

Comment: To ensure that the parent exits after the child, call one of the `wait` family of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Forking is not the same as threading. A fork creates a copy of the process. The
values of the variables in the child process would have the same as the
variables of the parent process **at the time of the `fork()`**. That means that
the child variables inherit the values from the parent, but changes of the
child variables are not visible by the parent.

If the parent needs to wait for the child to exit, it must call
[`wait` or `waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid). Also if the parent needs to get a value from the child, the parent and the child
should comunicate with each other, for example using a [pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).

The following code shows how parant and child communicate with each other and
how the parent should wait for a child to exit:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int comm[2];

    // create pipe

    if(pipe(comm) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not create pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not fork");
        close(comm[0]);
        close(comm[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        // CHILD

        // closing reading end of the pipe
        close(comm[0]);

        do_some_work();

        int result = 50;

        // write to the parant through the pipe
        write(comm[1], &result, sizeof result);

        // closing writing end
        close(comm[1]);

        exit(0);
    }

    // PARENT

    // close writing end of pipe
    close(comm[1]);

    puts("Now waiting for the child to exit...");

    // parent waits for child to exit
    int child_status;
    if(waitpid(pid, &child_status, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not wait");
        close(comm[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // if child exited without any error
    if(WIFEXITED(child_status) && WEXITSTATUS(child_status) == 0)
    {
        // read answer from the child
        int answer;
        read(comm[0], &answer, sizeof answer);

        printf("Child answered with %d\n", answered);
    }

    // closing reading end of pipe
    close(comm[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to keep both ends of the pipe open in both child and parent. Program falls into inf. loop again!

Comment: @user3598542 without seeing your new code, I cannot see why.

Answer (score 2):

The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces. At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same content.

There is concept called **Copy on Write** (CoW); it's good to have knowledge about it-

> Copy on Write is an optimization where the page tables are set up so that the parent and child process start off sharing all of the same memory, and only the pages that are written to by either process are copied when needed.

*[Above is copied from my own answer to an old thread]*

In your program you are doing:

```
   while(T_Child < 50)
   {//to ensure parent exits after child
       delay(1);
   }
```

The `T_Child` is initialized with `0` before `fork`. Because the address spaces are separate, when the child process modifies the value of `T_Child`, CoW creates a copy of its page — but the parent copy of `T_Child` still has the initial value `0`. The parent process is not making any change in the value in `T_Child`. So, the `while` loop condition `T_Child < 50` will always true and the loop will execute infinitely.

Instead, you should wait for child process to exit using [**waitpid**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) system call. In place of `while(T_Child < 50){..` loop, you should do:

```
waitpid(procid,&status,0);
```

This will make parent process wait till child process exits.